# Linux desktop with windows that are not always or not just rectangular (and can be spline-adjusted)

Tags: windows, linux, linux-distribution, window-manager, visual-design

I was thinking the following would look good on some Linux distros such as COSMIC, if only developers devoted some time effort and energy to do so. It might even get replicated on some versions of Windows.

The idea is to have a desktop where applications that can program their app border (and let it resize through a vector spline border control adjustment border widget, (just as though it was an inkscape shape).

I would look into the Qt toolkit as a predecessor framework.

But I think a new software framework, and API, would be needed, for this.

Because Qt had stuff such as software springs between software widgets that can be arranged horizontally, vertically, or obliquely, last time I checked this out in version 2 of Qt.

So, it would be nice, if at least some apps could have interiors that were programmed in some way to adjust as the border changed from rectangular to some other shape.

You could even arrange apps in the shape of biology cells in the desktop (with the cells being different shapes and sizes).

I think it would be nice.

I think it would be interesting.

I think it would be a nice break.

Who is willing to do this?

Where can I find such functionality?

Thanks.